# issue with parsing vsdx xml file

Tags: xml, parsing, visio

I am trying to parse vsdx xml files.But,while parsing Dynamic connector,it does not give information of which two shapes its connecting to.Anybody have any advice?I am looking into page1.xml because it has all the information of vsdx file.

Comment: Hello Raj, Actually, I'm trying to add some shapes and connections in .vsdx format. I have insert the shape xml in page1.xml, but when I try to open it it doesn't change anything even though the shape xml is existing. can you help me or give me some advice how did you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you seem to be really a brave one, to dig into that :) I think to understand how to get connection information you may need learn what is ShapeSheet in Visio, and how shape connections are actually build.

Anyways, you need to look for `<Connects>` part in that file, the connection info is not stored in shapes, it is stored separately. Note that this section contains not the connections between 2-d shapes, but connection between ShapeSheet cells basically. For example, the below example describes ONE "connection" between shape `1` to shape `2` using connector shape `3`.

```
<Connects>
    <Connect FromSheet='3' FromCell='EndX' FromPart='12' ToSheet='2' ToCell='PinX' ToPart='3'/>
    <Connect FromSheet='3' FromCell='BeginX' FromPart='9' ToSheet='1' ToCell='PinX' ToPart='3'/>
</Connects>
```

Make sure you checked out this link (and link to [pkgVisio](http://pkgvisio.codeplex.com/documentation) at the bottom of that page, it may turn to be helpful for you)

[How to: Manipulate the Visio 2013 file format programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj649391.aspx)